# How to give database configurations in IBM Integration Bus tool kit

Tags: mysql, ibm-integration-bus

I'm quite new to IIB and MQ Explorer.
How can I give the database configurations for the database node in IIB(IBM Integration Bus) tool kit?
In IIB I have a message flow which consists of MQinput>Database
For MQ input passing the xml which consists of student details.
Here want to use MYSQL database configurations.
I want to store the student details in MySQL database.

Thanks in advance, if the question is lacking information, please let me know.

when I clicked on database node didn't find any properties which are related to hostname, driver, username and password.

I'm running everything locally because I'm still learning (Local Queues as well, if it matters).

Comment: Why did you tag `db2` if your qustion concerns mysql?   This is not a question about programming or software-development.   This is a configuration question.   Refer to the documentation here https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/integration-bus/10.0?topic=database-creating-connection-profile